# MVC 3 route binding issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having an issue trying to bind 2 database values to the URL my global.asax file is correct as

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{stitle}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "article", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, stitle= UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults

        );
```

The issue i am having is with my controller for some reason i cannot get the Second value to return here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id,string stitle)
    {

        Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);  
      stitle = (from s in db.Articles where id == s.ArticleID select s.stitle).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(article);
    }
```

is there someway that i can return **stitle** or include it within the article since the **stitle** is a string value from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the last parameter of a route can be optional. So in your case the `id` parameter can no longer be optional:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{stitle}",
    new { controller = "article", action = "Index", stitle = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then make sure that you are generating the proper link to this action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "index", "article", new { id = "123", stitle = "some-title" }, null)
```

and the generated url should look like this:

```
href="/article/index/123/some-title"
```